# Prevent VS to jump to call return when breaking debug

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When you break the debug in Visual Studio (through the `Break All` menu or the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>BREAK</kbd> by default), it jumps to the line of the `call return`.

(In my case, using winforms, it jumps to the `Application.Run();` line of the *Program.cs* file).

It's kind of annoying when you're debugging a method and every time you hit `Break All`, the focus is set back on a file you weren't working on.

Is it possible to disable that jump? I couldn't find any option in the Debugging part of the VS options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not "jumping" - it's breaking to the currently executing line of code.  This is the behavior, and is not configurable.

If you want to have it stop at a specific line of code where you're working, you can just set a break point there, instead.  This will cause it to break at your breakpoint as soon as it executes the code there.